# How to point the build folder in Nodejs for NextJS app to deploy on cPanel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, cpanel

I am trying a NextJS (FRONT-END) + NodeJS (API) app and want to deploy it in cPanel. But I am unable to do the deployment. Can anyone suggest to me how to point the build folder in NodeJS for the Front-End part so that I can run the NodeJS server and it automatically serve the front end? [Just like React Build Folder-- Where is the build folder in NextJS). TIA